# Seleccionar registros donde el valor de la columna cambia

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

tengo una tabla que guarda el estado de varios sensores, estos pueden ser encendidos o apagados
¿es posible hacer una consulta donde los resultados sean cuando el sensor cambia de estado?

```
+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|      time       | sensor1 | sensor2 | sensor3 | sensor4 |
+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 5/17/2021 02:32 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       0 | 
| 5/17/2021 04:42 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       0 |
| 5/17/2021 06:28 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       0 |
| 5/17/2021 06:44 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       0 |
| 5/17/2021 08:16 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       0 |
| 5/17/2021 09:07 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       0 |
| 5/17/2021 09:11 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       0 |
| 5/17/2021 09:11 |       0 |       1 |       0 |       0 | <- esta linea donde sensor3 cambia de valor
| 5/17/2021 09:12 |       0 |       1 |       0 |       0 |
| 5/17/2021 09:12 |       0 |       1 |       0 |       0 |
| 5/17/2021 09:13 |       0 |       1 |       0 |       0 |
| 5/17/2021 09:13 |       0 |       1 |       0 |       0 |
| 5/17/2021 09:13 |       0 |       1 |       0 |       0 |
| 5/17/2021 09:43 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 | <- sensor3 y/o sensor4 cambia de valor
| 5/17/2021 09:53 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 5/17/2021 11:13 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 5/17/2021 11:13 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 5/17/2021 11:13 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 5/17/2021 11:14 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 5/17/2021 11:14 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 5/17/2021 11:14 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 5/17/2021 11:14 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 5/17/2021 11:36 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 5/17/2021 12:22 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 5/17/2021 12:52 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 5/17/2021 13:30 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 5/17/2021 13:31 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 5/17/2021 13:31 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 5/17/2021 13:38 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 5/17/2021 13:47 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 5/17/2021 13:52 |       0 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 5/17/2021 13:54 |       0 |       0 |       1 |       1 | <- sensor2 cambia de valor
| 5/17/2021 13:54 |       0 |       0 |       1 |       1 |
+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

es indiferente si tengo que hacer la consulta por cada columna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo dos formas de conseguir lo que quieres, en ambos casos he usado estos datos de prueba (similares a los que indicas).

| Fecha | Sensor1 | Sensor2 | Sensor3 | Sensor4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-05 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-05-06 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-05-07 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-05-08 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-05-09 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-05-10 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

1. **Usando variables de acumulación**. Esta query se basa en definir variables que se van asignando en cada fila y permiten comprobar de forma sencilla con la fila anterior.

```
select * from (select 
    @sensor1ant as sensor1ant, -- Dato de la fila anterior
    @sensor1ant := e.sensor1 as sensor1, -- Acumular y mostrar dato actual
    @sensor2ant as sensor2ant,
    @sensor2ant := e.sensor2 as sensor2,
    @sensor3ant as sensor3ant,
    @sensor3ant := e.sensor3 as sensor3,
    @sensor4ant as sensor4ant,
    @sensor4ant := e.sensor4 as sensor4,
    fecha
from
    (
        -- Tabla que genera los valores previos para la primera fila.
        select
            @sensor1ant := -1,
            @sensor2ant := -1,
            @sensor3ant := -1,
            @sensor4ant := -1
    ) as i,
    datosSensor as e
) datos
where 
-- Ignorar los datos de la comparación de la primera fila
not (sensor1ant = -1 or sensor2ant = -1 or sensor3ant = -1 or sensor4ant = -1) 
and (
sensor1ant <> sensor1
or
sensor2ant <> sensor2
or
sensor3ant <> sensor3
or
sensor4ant <> sensor4
)
```

En la que obtendría los siguientes resultados:

| sensor1ant | sensor1 | sensor2ant | sensor2 | sensor3ant | sensor3 | sensor4ant | sensor4 | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2021-05-07 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2021-05-08 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 |

Esta opción podría refinarse concatenando los datos de los sensores como indica @Durgeoble en un comentario:

```
select * from (select 
    @sensoresant as sensoresant, 
    @sensoresant := concat(e.sensor1,e.sensor2, e.sensor3, e.sensor4) as sensores, 
    fecha
from
    (
        -- Tabla que genera los valores previos para la primera fila.
        select
            @sensoresant := ""
    ) as i,
    datosSensor as e
) datos
where 
sensoresant <> "" -- Ignorar los datos de la comparación de la primera fila
and 
sensoresant <> sensores;
```

y sus resultados:

| sensoresant | sensores | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0011 | 1011 | 2021-05-07 00:00:00 |
| 1011 | 1111 | 2021-05-08 00:00:00 |
| 1111 | 1110 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 |

2. **Generar Ids secuenciales para cada fila y usar un join para unir cada fila con la siguiente**. La query quedaría así:

```
select * from 
(SELECT @rowid:=@rowid+1 as rowid, datosSensor.*
FROM menestest.datosSensor, (SELECT @rowid:=0) as init) `dato` 
-- Primera subquery usa @rowid para obtener generar los ids
inner join 
(SELECT @rowid2:=@rowid2+1 as rowid, datosSensor.*
FROM menestest.datosSensor, (SELECT @rowid2:=0) as init)  `datoSiguiente` 
-- Segunda subquery usa @rowid2 para obtener el mismo conjunto de ids
on dato.rowid = datoSiguiente.rowid +1 -- Unir la fila con la siguiente
where -- Obtener las filas con valores distintos
dato.sensor1 <> datoSiguiente.sensor1 or 
dato.sensor2 <> datoSiguiente.sensor2 or
dato.sensor3 <> datoSiguiente.sensor3 or
dato.sensor4 <> datoSiguiente.sensor4;
```

Que resultaría en los siguientes valores:

| rowid | fecha | sensor1 | sensor2 | sensor3 | sensor4 | rowid | fecha | sensor1 | sensor2 | sensor3 | sensor4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2021-05-07 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2021-05-06 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2021-05-08 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 2021-05-07 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 6 | 2021-05-10 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Desconozco cual de las dos obtendrá un mejor rendimiento en entornos con muchos datos pero creo que será la primera al no necesitar join.

La primera técnica la he desarrollado en base a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20849340/3628830)

Comment: interesante forma de hacerlo, entiendo que si concateno todos los valores que quiero comprobar y lo comparo con la concatenación de la fila anterior el resultado será el mismo y quedará mas legible, voy a probarlo y te digo, gracias

Comment: @Durgeoble Tienes toda la razón!! No se me había ocurrido, voy a editar la respuesta para incluir la concatenación!